# Magento 2 REST API - Creating a new cart deactivates old one

Tags: magento2

I'm using the Magento 2 REST API to process orders. I'm using the admin token to handle all the API calls.

Problem is that if I get two requests at the same time, the first request fails because the second one creates a new cart.

I'm wondering if there is a way to work with multiple carts at the same time?

I'm able to get the first cart details and the value of `is_active` is false.

I'll have to add a queue if there is no option.